# Cant access data in database, mysqli functions do not work but show no error

Tags: php, mysql, database

-I want to get the Id of user so I can show a welcome message in his profile but I cant seem to return the id. Maybe it is a problem in the query but when I run the code it only shows: "Error:" so I cant seem to find what is wrong. 
-I have tried different sintaxes for the queries and they also work when testing them in phpmyadmin with concrete values. 
-"Emri" is firstname in my language.

My db connection: 
$dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'oms_db');

my fuctions in a file fuctions.php:

```
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('dbc.php');

function getId($dbc, $username)
{ 
    $query = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username='.$username.'";
    $q = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
   if($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
            return $r[id];
        }
        else {
            echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc);
        }
}
function getData($dbc, $id, $data) 
{   
    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='.$id.'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
    echo $array[$data];
}
```

How I called the fuctions:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        if(!isset($_GET['id'])){    
    $userId = getId($dbc, $_SESSION['username']);
        }
         echo "Welcome to profile, ".getData($dbc, $userId, 'emri');
```

I have read 10 or more posts in stakoverflow but haven't found a solution. I think it is a problem with phpmyadmin or maybe queries dont work within a function.

Comment: Use proper tag in your question.

Comment: definitely a quotes concat issue '.$username.' and make sure you started the session

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I have session_start(); in the index.php or it should be added in every file?! when I remove the quotes and the query is like this: "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=.$username" , it gives me a Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: just remove the dots  '$username' or add double quotes  '".$username."'

Comment: plus if you are running this code in phpmyadmin it wont work. it doesn't work with variables as such so I don't know why you talk about phpmyadmin

Comment: @Fred-ii- WERE THE DOTS -_- OMG!!! thank you...ps- I have mentioned 'with concrete values'

Comment: you are welcome, glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the quotes and concatenates in

```
 WHERE username='.$username.'";
```

either remove the dots

```
 WHERE username='$username'";
```

or add double quotes

```
 WHERE username='".$username."'";
```

since we are dealing with strings

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html

Look into using prepared statements also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement